# php code to store query values in array

Tags: php, sql, loops, mysqli, phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZuPH.png)Database sample:

[image: Database sample]

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM  `Aadhar` WHERE FSC LIKE        CONTACT($FSC)");

 $data = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $id = array_shift($row); // Shifts first element
     $data[$id] = $row; 
     print($data[]);
```

I want to store the uid numbers in an array and pring by currusponding FSC number.
by giving FSC number , logic has to do this.
I tried.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please use mysqli_* or PDO. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection if you plan to include user input directly in to the SQL query.

This is how you do it in PDO:

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbname", "root", "password");
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Aadhar WHERE FSC LIKE :fsc");
$query->bindParam(":fsc", $fsc = '%'.$FSC.'%'); 

if($query->execute()) {
    $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //get the results in the form of an associative array
} else {
    die("Query failed");
}

var_dump($data);
```